# Can I include repeated measures in adonis2 PERMANOVA (vegan package)?

Tags: r, vegan

I am looking to determine whether there are differences in a plant community between years using PERMANOVA. There was a herd of cows grazing a series of plots each year and the plants within these plots were remeasured each year after grazing.

Now, I would like to look at if the plant community changes with each year of grazing. However, since we measured the same plots each year, I am wondering if there is a way to account for repeated plot measurements within adonis2's PERMANOVA function?

I can run a PERMANOVA on the plant community between years but I am nervous I am not accounting for the lack of independence with repeated plot measurements

Comment: This is essentially a data modeling question. If you need help choosing the corect model for your data, then you should first ask for help at [stats.se] to find the best way to account for your repeated measures.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.